# In angular using interpolation for assigning the value of title of span element in HTML.Adding &#13; for a line break is not working

Tags: angular

Below is the sample code format used for above question.

```
export interface IMarketVariables {
    MarketDescription: string;
}
```

and in marketcomponent.ts file I am assigning the value as :

```
marketDescription: IMarketVariables = { MarketDescription: '' }
this.marketDescription = 'Market1market2&#13market3market4'
```

in marketcomponent.html:

```
<span title="{{this.marketDescription}}">MarketName</span> -- break is not working
<span title="Market1market2&#13market3market4">MarketName</span> -- Working fine with break
```

Here the break tag &#13 is not getting applied with interpolation

So can u please help in finding out the reason behind not applying break tag with interpolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the how the angular parser works :

- the parser consider the string not to contain any reserved pattern so
  it doesnt work with interpolataion
- while when you put the variable directly the parser looks for the reserved patterns and when it sees `&#13` it applies it to the final output

[EDIT] this is how you can achieve what you want to achieve

you can use new line character in the string or use literal string with back quote like the example below

marketcomponent.html

```
<span title="{{this.marketDescription}}">MarketName</span>
```

marketcomponent.ts

```
this.marketDescription = `Market1market2
market3market4`;
// or 
this.marketDescription = "Market1market2\nmarket3market4";
```

Comment: Thank u..Is there any other way..that i can pass the value from .ts and break is applied... instead of hardcoding the value in html